# Java program keeps on crashing

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, crash

I am making a space shooter in java. When I run the program and play for a minute, it works, but part way through, as soon as a bullet comes into contact with an enemy, the program crashes and gives me the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:638)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:414)
at main.Game.checkCollisions(Game.java:185)
at main.Game.tick(Game.java:118)
at main.Game.run(Game.java:95)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What is causing this crash? How can I fix it?

Here is the area of code where the error is happening:

```
void checkCollisions() {
        for(int i = 0; i < Shoot.allBullets.size(); i++){  
            for(int j = 0; j < Enemy.allEnemies.size(); j++){
                if(new Rectangle((int)Shoot.allBullets.get(i).x, (int)Shoot.allBullets.get(i).y, 23, 48).intersects(new Rectangle((int) Enemy.allEnemies.get(j).x, (int) Enemy.allEnemies.get(j).y, 64, 64))) {
                    bulletIntersectsEnemy(i, j);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the rest of the code:

Game.java

```
package main;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable, KeyListener {

    //declare values
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static final int WIDTH = 800;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 600;
    public static final String TITLE = "Space Shooter";

    private boolean running = false;
    private Thread thread;

    private Player player;

    private BufferedImage playerImage;
    private BufferedImage bulletImage;
    private BufferedImage enemyImage;

    int playerx;
    int playery;

    int round = 1;

    public Game() {
        //
        player = new Player((WIDTH/2)-32, HEIGHT-200); 

        //allocates all file resources
        try {
            playerImage = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/player.png"));
            bulletImage = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/bullet.png"));
            enemyImage = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/enemy.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        requestFocusInWindow();
    }

    //starts thread
    private synchronized void start() {
        if (running)
            return;

        running = true;
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    //stops thread
    private synchronized void stop() {
        if (!running)
            return;

        running = false;
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.exit(1);
    }

    @Override
    //game loop
    public void run() {     
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        final double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
        double ns  = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
        double delta = 0;
        int updates = 0;
        int frames = 0;
        long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (running) {
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
            lastTime = now;
            if (delta > 1) {
                tick();
                updates++;
                delta--;
            }
            render();
            frames++;

            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000) {
                timer += 1000;
                System.out.println(updates + " TICKS, " + frames + " FPS");
                updates = 0;
                frames = 0;
            }
        }
        stop(); 
    }

    //updates sprite locations
    public void tick() {
        playerx = player.getX();
        playery = player.getY(); 
        Shoot.updateBullets();
        Enemy.updateEnemies();
        checkCollisions();
    }

    //renders sprites
    public void render() {
        //setting up triple-buffering
        BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
        if (bs == null) {
            createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }
        Graphics g  = bs.getDrawGraphics();

        //////////////////////////////////

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK); g.fillRect(0,0,getWidth(), getHeight());
        g.drawImage(playerImage, playerx, playery, this); 

        if (Shoot.allBullets.size() != 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < Shoot.allBullets.size(); i++) {
                int bulletx = (int) Shoot.allBullets.get(i).x;
                int bullety = (int) Shoot.allBullets.get(i).y;  
                g.drawImage(bulletImage, bulletx + 21, bullety, this);
            }
        }

        if (Enemy.allEnemies.size() != 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < Enemy.allEnemies.size(); i++) {
                int enemyx = (int) Enemy.allEnemies.get(i).x;
                int enemyy = (int) Enemy.allEnemies.get(i).y;
                g.drawImage(enemyImage, enemyx, enemyy, this);
            }
        } else {
            Enemy.createEnemies(round);
            round++;
        }

        //////////////////////////////////

        g.dispose();
        bs.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
            Shoot.addBullet(player.getX(), player.getY());
        }
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            player.setY(playery -= 20);
        } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            player.setY(playery += 20);
        } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            player.setX(playerx += 40);
        } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            player.setX(playerx -= 40);
        } 
    }

    void checkCollisions() {
        for(int i = 0; i < Shoot.allBullets.size(); i++){  
            for(int j = 0; j < Enemy.allEnemies.size(); j++){
                if(new Rectangle((int)Shoot.allBullets.get(i).x, (int)Shoot.allBullets.get(i).y, 23, 48).intersects(new Rectangle((int) Enemy.allEnemies.get(j).x, (int) Enemy.allEnemies.get(j).y, 64, 64))) {
                    bulletIntersectsEnemy(i, j);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void bulletIntersectsEnemy(int bulletIndex, int enemyIndex) {
        Shoot.allBullets.remove(bulletIndex);
        Enemy.allEnemies.remove(enemyIndex);
    }

    /*
    public void manageCollisions() {
        for (int i = 0; i < Shoot.allBullets.size(); i++) {
            for (int e = 0; e < Enemy.allEnemies.size(); e++) {
                if (Shoot.allBullets.get(i).x > Enemy.allEnemies.get(e).y) {
                    if (Shoot.allBullets.get(i).x < Enemy.allEnemies.get(e).y) {
                        if (Shoot.allBullets.get(i).y == Enemy.allEnemies.get(e).y + 64) {
                            System.out.println("Collision Detected!");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    */

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Game game = new Game();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(TITLE);

        frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.add(game);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        frame.setVisible(true); 

        game.start();

    }

}
```

Enemy.java

```
package main;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Enemy {

    static ArrayList<Point> allEnemies = new ArrayList<Point>();

    public static ArrayList<Point> createEnemies(int round) {
        for (int i = 0; i < round; i++) {
            Point newEnemyLocation = new Point((int) (Math.random()*Game.WIDTH), 0);
            double newx = validate(newEnemyLocation.x); 
            newEnemyLocation.x = newx;
            allEnemies.add(newEnemyLocation);
        }
        return allEnemies; 
    }

    private static double validate(double x) {
        for (int i = 0; i < allEnemies.size();i++) {
            Point otherEnemy = allEnemies.get(i);
            if (x > otherEnemy.x) {
                if (x < (otherEnemy.x - 64)) {
                    x += 200;
                }
            }
        }
        if (x > Game.WIDTH - 64) {
             x -= 64;
        }
        if (x < 64) {
            x += 64;
        }
        return x;
    }

    public static ArrayList<Point> updateEnemies() {
        if (allEnemies.size() != 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < allEnemies.size(); i++) {
                Point enemyLocation = allEnemies.get(i);
                if (enemyLocation.y <= Game.HEIGHT) {
                    allEnemies.get(i).y += 1;
                } else {
                    allEnemies.remove(i);
                }   
            }
        }
        return allEnemies;
    }

}
```

Shoot.java

```
package main;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Shoot {

    static ArrayList<Point> allBullets = new ArrayList<Point>();

    public static void addBullet(int x, int y) {
        allBullets.add(new Point(x, y)); 
    }

    public static ArrayList<Point> getAllBulletPosistions() {
        return allBullets;
    }

    public static void updateBullets() {
        if (allBullets.size() != 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < allBullets.size(); i++) {
                allBullets.get(i).y -= 5; 
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Player.java

```
package main;

public class Player {

    int x, y; 

    public Player(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

}
```

Comment: you need to provide some code, just the reason of the exception is not enough

Comment: i did, i gave a link where you can download my code from

Comment: You should provide code - just the relevant piece of code, which you should work out by normal diagnostics, debugging etc - *in the question*.

Comment: Basically, it looks like you're calling `get()` on an `ArrayList` with an invalid index. We don't know how that's happening though.

Comment: ill add the code into the question, i just didnt put it into the question before because I thought it could make the post seem really bug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void checkCollisions() {
    for(int i = 0; i < Shoot.allBullets.size(); i++){  
        for(int j = 0; j < Enemy.allEnemies.size(); j++){
            if(new Rectangle((int)Shoot.allBullets.get(i).x, (int)Shoot.allBullets.get(i).y, 23, 48).intersects(new Rectangle((int) Enemy.allEnemies.get(j).x, (int) Enemy.allEnemies.get(j).y, 64, 64))) {
                bulletIntersectsEnemy(i, j);
            }
        }
    }
}

void bulletIntersectsEnemy(int bulletIndex, int enemyIndex) {
    Shoot.allBullets.remove(bulletIndex);
    Enemy.allEnemies.remove(enemyIndex);
}
```

The problem is that you actually remove your bullets prematurely.
Let's say you only fire one bullet and there are three enemies. It hits the first one.

Now you remove the bullet from the Shoot.allBullets list but your inner for loop isn't finished yet. It will still keep trying to see if

```
Shoot.allBullets.get(0)
```

(i is still 0) intersects with the other enemies. Except that Bullet doesn't exist anymore, so you get that exception.

Comment: I fixed this and it works now! Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help. I'd appreciate if you marked this as the right answer ;)